# VSCode: Way to see what extensions are doing what?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a simple TypeScript project I'm working on. I have a bunch of extensions running and everything works great. There's one file in particular, though, that when I edit I get all sorts of weirdness that happens. Intellisense takes forever to load, syntax highlighting goes funky, discovered problems refresh sporadically. I've tried removing/disabling a ton of extensions trying to find the culprit, but so far no luck.

Is there a "Task Manager" view for extensions? A way to see what extensions are active at any point in time or which have been running for a long time? Right now, I'm just shooting in the dark. But if I could see that an extension was taking a long time or something, I might be able to track down the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is indeed a method for profiling extensions. It's not as pretty as the Windows Task Manager, but it's something.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Performance-Issues#profile-the-running-extensions

My problem ended up being a GitHub extension.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that such a utility exists.
Extensions execute in the context of VS Code itself, so their individual execution
is hard to distinguish.

If you know how to cause the problem, to locate the problematic extension
just repeat the action on that file, while each time disabling some more
extensions, until you find the one causing the problem.

See the Microsoft article
[Extension Marketplace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery)
for how to list the extensions, disable and re-enable.

Comment: The hard part is replicating the problem. By reviewing the @installed list yet again, I did finally see I had two different `tslint` extensions running, and uninstalling one seems to have fixed the problem. Ugh. Time to look at the vscode code and see if there's something I can contribute! :) Thanks for your time.